# delete Menu Item from unity after finishes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am coding a script, that will help me, to organize my folders un unity, the problem is that when I click on the new "Unity" Menu Item created by the script, I want to delete that script automatically after creating all the folders.

```
[MenuItem("Unity/Create structure")]
static void CreateFolder() {

    var items = new string[] {
        "Sprites",
        "Scripts",
        "Animation",
        "Materials",
        "Prefabs",
        "Media",
        "Plugins",
        "Models",
        "Textures",
        "Shaders"
    };

    Array.Sort(items);

    foreach (var item in items) {
        string folders = AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets", item);
        AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(folders);
    }

    File.Delete($"{Application.dataPath}/Organize.cs");
    AssetDatabase.Refresh();
```

For some reason this doesn't work
by the way this script is in my asset folder

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem with your code. Are you sure your script is named `Organize.cs`?

Comment: Yes wait a second I will update my Question

Comment: it deletes the script for you

Comment: Your script is named `Org*r*anize` and not `Organize`...

Comment: Plus you just revealed phone numbers, names and pictures of people in your screenshot.

Comment: haha sorry it works, but when iI deleted it, I get this warning ``` A meta data file (.meta) exists but its asset 'Assets/Structure.cs' can't be found. When moving or deleting files outside of Unity, please ensure that the corresponding .meta file is moved or deleted along with it.
UnityEditor.AssetDatabase:Refresh () ```

Comment: Why instead of deleting the script completely rather somewhere store a serialized bool and rather only disable the menu item?

Comment: And the last warning already tells you exactly what to do if you want to prevent the warning ;) otherwise you can also simply ignore that one ^^

Comment: **Please do not add pictures of personal and contact information you are not allowed to share on the internet!!**

Comment: Sorry, but did you really have to put negative in my question?

Comment: As you can see from my script, I am learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code fixed, when you delete a file don't forget to delete its meta file too.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

public class Organize : MonoBehaviour
{
    [MenuItem("Unity/Create structure")]
    static void CreateFolder() {
    
        var items = new string[] {
            "Sprites",
            "Scripts",
            "Animation",
            "Materials",
            "Prefabs",
            "Media",
            "Plugins",
            "Models",
            "Textures",
            "Shaders"
        };
    
        Array.Sort(items);
    
        foreach (var item in items) {
            string folders = AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets", item);
            AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(folders);
        }
    
        AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset("Assets/Organize.cs");
        AssetDatabase.Refresh();
    }
}
```